# Angular service spec not reaching expectations for observables

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, specifications

## Problem

I'm trying to write a spec in jasmine for an Angular service I have.  The service wraps the `@azure/msal-angular` and also uses the Microsoft Graph API to get the logged in user's profile picture.  I'm having trouble getting the test to succeed.  All I'm trying to do is verify that when the Graph API errors out when asking for a picture (i.e. there is a 404 error), that that error is caught, and the default image from my assets folder is returned instead.

However, I'm getting the following error:
[image]

Below is my service under test, and the test itself.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

### Service

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BroadcastService, MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { Account, AuthError, AuthResponse, ClientAuthError } from 'msal';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, shareReplay, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { GraphUser } from '../../models';
import { LocalBlobService } from '../../services';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;

    /** TODO: Cache locally
     * - clear on logout
     * - how often to refresh?
     */
    graphUser$: Observable<GraphUser>;

    /** TODO: Cache locally
     * - clear on logout
     * - how often to refresh?
     */
    graphPicture$: Observable<SafeUrl>;

    get loginFailure$(): Observable<any> {
        return this._loginFailure$.asObservable();
    }

    get loginSuccess$(): Observable<any> {
        return this._loginSuccess$.asObservable();
    }

    get user(): Account {
        const user = this._msal.getAccount();
        this.isLoggedIn = !!user;
        return user;
    }

    private _loginFailure$ = new ReplaySubject<any>();
    private _loginSuccess$ = new ReplaySubject<any>();

    constructor(
        private readonly _http: HttpClient,
        private readonly _msal: MsalService,
        private readonly _broadcasts: BroadcastService,
        private readonly _sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        private readonly _localBlob: LocalBlobService
    ) {
        this._msal.handleRedirectCallback(this.redirectCallback);
        this.getGraphUserInfo();

        this._broadcasts.subscribe(
            'msal:loginFailure',
            this.loginFailureCallback
        );

        this._broadcasts.subscribe(
            'msal:loginSuccess',
            this.loginSuccessCallback
        );
    }

    updateUserProfilePhoto(file) {
        return this._http
            .put(environment.AD.pictureUrl, file)
            .pipe(
                catchError((error, caught) => this.handlePictureError(error))
            );
    }

    private getGraphUserInfo() {
        if (this.user) {
            this.graphUser$ = this.getGraphUser();
            this.graphPicture$ = this.getGraphPicture();
        }
    }

    private getGraphPicture(): Observable<SafeUrl> {
        return this._http
            .get(environment.AD.pictureUrl, {
                responseType: 'blob',
            })
            .pipe(
                catchError((error, caught) => this.handlePictureError(error)),
                switchMap(blob => this._localBlob.readAsDataURL(blob)),
                map(picture => this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(picture)),
                shareReplay(1)
            );
    }

    private getGraphUser(): Observable<GraphUser> {
        return this._http.get<GraphUser>(environment.AD.graphUrl).pipe(
            catchError((error, caught) => throwError(error)),
            shareReplay()
        );
    }

    private loginSuccessCallback = payload => {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this._loginSuccess$.next();
        this.getGraphUserInfo();
    };

    private loginFailureCallback = payload => {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
        this._loginFailure$.next();
    };

    private redirectCallback = (
        redirectError: AuthError,
        redirectResponse: AuthResponse
    ) => {
        if (redirectError) {
            console.error(redirectError);
            return;
        }
        console.log(redirectResponse);
    };

    private handlePictureError(error: ClientAuthError): Observable<Blob> {
        console.log(error);
        return this._http.get('/assets/images/defaultAvatarSmall.png', {
            responseType: 'blob',
        });
    }
}
```

### Test

```js
it('should return default image if graph API picture fails', (done: DoneFn) => {
    // Arrange
    const spy = spyOn(TestBed.inject(HttpClient), 'get')
        .withArgs(environment.AD.graphUrl)
        .and.callThrough()
        .withArgs(environment.AD.pictureUrl, {
            responseType: 'blob',
        } as any)
        .and.returnValue(throwError(new ClientAuthError('')))
        .withArgs('/assets/images/defaultAvatarSmall.png', {
            responseType: 'blob',
        } as any)
        .and.callThrough();

     // Act
    const service: AuthService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
    service.graphPicture$.subscribe(
        () => {

            // Assert
            expect(spy.calls.allArgs()).toEqual([
                [environment.AD.graphUrl],
                [
                    environment.AD.pictureUrl,
                    { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' },
                ],
                [
                    '/assets/images/defaultAvatarSmall.png',
                    { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' },
                ],
            ]);
            done();
        },
        error => {
            expect(1).toEqual(1);
            done();
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Today was a long day because of this one...

I changed `getGraphPicture` in `AuthService` to be defined like the following:

```js
    private getGraphPicture(): Observable<SafeUrl> {
        // Observable stream of image requests where errors are not emitted.
        return onErrorResumeNext<Blob>(
            // Try the logged in user's pictureUrl first
            this._http.get<Blob>(environment.AD.pictureUrl, {
                responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
            }),
            // Try the default avatar picture in assets next
            this._http.get<Blob>('/assets/images/defaultAvatarSmall.png', {
                responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
            })
        ).pipe(
            first(), // Only grab the first successful emission
            switchMap(blob => this._localBlob.readAsDataURL(blob)),
            map(picture => this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(picture)),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
    }
```

I then wrote my test like this:

```js
    it('should return default image if graph API picture fails', fakeAsync(() => {
        // Arrange
        const spy = spyOn(TestBed.inject(HttpClient), 'get')
            .withArgs(environment.AD.graphUrl)
            .and.callThrough()
            .withArgs(environment.AD.pictureUrl, {
                responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
            })
            .and.returnValue(throwError(new ClientAuthError('')))
            .withArgs('/assets/images/defaultAvatarSmall.png', {
                responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
            })
            .and.callThrough();

        // Act
        const service: AuthService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
        tick();

        expect(spy.calls.allArgs()).toEqual([
            [environment.AD.graphUrl],
            [environment.AD.pictureUrl, { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }],
            [
                '/assets/images/defaultAvatarSmall.png',
                { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' },
            ],
        ]);
    }));
```